# How to parse a csv file on the local machine using Papa parser?

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I want to parse a csv file using Papa parser in my .hbs file(Front end). But it is giving data as null . How should i tackle this problem . This is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.2/papaparse.min.js"></script>
function handleFileSelect() {

    var file="D:\ExpenseTracker\out.csv"
    Papa.parse(file, {
      delimiter: ",", 
      header: true,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      complete: function(results) {
        data = results;
        console.log("data is: ",data);
      }
    });
    console.log("data is: ",data);
  }
```

Comment: you can't open files like that in javascript, that would be a huge security risk

Comment: how should i open the files in javascript?@FlashThunder

Comment: check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Yes it worked ! thanks alot .